# Conditional testing on checkbox in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a checkbox which I want to check if it is not checked and want to uncheck it if it is checked in Cypress. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to the community. What have you tried so far? Can you add your test code of you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

[Conditional testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing) is not recommended by Cypress, but it's possible to deal with this situation like this:

html:

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mytestcheckbox" />
  <label for="mytestcheckbox">Toggle me!</label>
</div>
```

and in Cypress:

```javascript
cy
  .get('#mytestcheckbox')
  .as('checkbox')
  .invoke('is', ':checked')
  .then(checked => {
    if (checked) {
      cy
        .get('@checkbox')
        .uncheck();
    } else {
      cy
        .get('@checkbox')
        .check();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , that did resolved my issue